# linked list add at position

Tags: java, linked-list

im having trouble adding nodes in between nodes in a link list....my code is as follows

```
public class Node {
    int data;
    int count;
    Node prev,next;
    public Node(int x){
        data=x;
        next=null;
        count=count++;
    }    
}
```

insert at position function

```
public void insertAtPos(int x ,int pos){

    if (start==null) {
        Node p=new Node(x);
        start=p; 
        NodeCount=NodeCount+1;
    } else {
        int i=1;
        Node current=start;
        if (pos>0){
            if (pos>NodeCount){
                System.out.println("The position exceeds the nodes in Linked List");
            }
             while (current!=null){
                 if (i==pos-1){
                     Node p=new Node(x);
                     p.next=current.next;
                     current.next=p;
                     return ;
                 }else{
                     current=current.next;
                     i++; 
                 }
                 NodeCount=NodeCount+1;

             }
        }else{

            System.out.println("The position exceeds the nodes in LL");
        }
    }
}
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[]args){
        LinkedList s=new LinkedList();
        s.insertFront(55);
        s.insertFront(33);
        s.insertFront(75);
        s.insertFront(83);
        s.insertEnd(59);

        s.display();

        s.insertAtPos(44,2);
        System.out.println("  ");
        s.display();
    }
```

The result I get replaces the Node with the one I provide...So my question is how do I modify the function to add the node in between

Comment: where do you call ` insertAtPos`?

Comment: main function ..sorry forgot to include that line

Comment: I think your `Node` class has a problem. In your constructor you write `count=count++`, but count isn't yet initialized for the `Node` you're creating. Also, usually, the `count` variable is stored in the head of the `LinkedList` to make it easy to update it.

Comment: I would create an `InsertAfter(Node newNode)` and `InsertBefore(Node newNode)` methode on class Node - and implement the needed logic there. f.e. InsertAfter: `var temp = Node.next;` to a temp var, set `Node.next = newNode;` then while newNote.next != null follow the next node's and look for the end of that node-chain. then `endOfNodeChain.next = temp;`

Comment: Using `node.InsertBefore(new Node(5))` then should take care of it. Drop the `count`- I dont see why it would be needed for a linked list... it is just one more variable that you have to keep track of when inserting/removing things from your list. You can calculate it on the fly: `public int Count { get { return 1 /* or 0 if you prefer not to count this node 
 - then it should be named ChidlCount or smth */ + (next is null ? 0 : next.Count);`

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
 if (i==pos-2){//stopping in previous node where you have to insert
       Node p=new Node(x);
       p.next=current.next;
       current.next=p;
       return ;
 }
```